# jQuery - Changing Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just new to learning some jQuery. I've been looking at some tutorials on w3schools. My aim is to change a shape color when I press a key. I can do this for a button but not a shape.

I'm using key code 8 which is backspace and am using this

```js
$("button").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 8) {
     $(this).css("background-color", "black");
    }
});
$("button").keyup(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>
Color
</button>
```

How would I do it for example with the following. I've tried several ways but can't seem to get it to work. Why won't changing the selector to the class name not work? Any tips are grateful. Thank you

```css
.shape{
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `button` natively accepts keyboard focus, whereas your `div` does not. Add this to `.shape`:

```html
<div class="shape" tabindex="0"></div>
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".shape").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 8) {
    // added for demo to prevent browser address change
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("background-color", "black");
  }
});
$(".shape").keyup(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```css
.shape {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape" tabindex="0"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mqsv5jw/1/)

To listen for any key event, without needing the focus to be on a specific element, you could adjust your code to the following:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 8) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".shape").css("background-color", "black");
  }
});
$(document).keyup(function() {
  $(".shape").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```css
.shape {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mqsv5jw/3/)

Comment: That worked. Why is it that I have to click on the shape before it will actually become responsive to my keyboard input. Is there anyway I could bypass that?

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate it. I have a much better understanding of this now. Thanks Andy H.